# How to extract and verify token sent from frontend

Tags: go, jwt, token, jwt-go

I am using "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go", and able to send a token to my frontend, and what I would like to know how I could retrieve the token sent from the frontend so that I can verify if the token that was sent is valid and if so the secured resource will be delivered.

Here is the token sent from frontend JavaScript:

```
headers: {
       'Authorization':'Bearer' + localStorage.getItem('id_token')
     }
```

Here is the code to send token

```
    token := jwt.New(jwt.GetSigningMethod("HS256"))
    claims := make(jwt.MapClaims)
    claims["userName"] = loginRequest.UserName
    claims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Minute * 60).Unix()
    token.Claims = claims
    tokenString, err := token.SignedString([]byte(SecretKey))
    tokenByte, err := json.Marshal(data)
    w.WriteHeader(201)
    w.Write(tokenByte)
```

Here is the code to verify the token

```
    func VerifyToken(r *http.Request) bool {

    reqToken := r.Header.Get("Authorization")
    token, err := jwt.Parse(reqToken, func(t *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return []byte(SecretKey), nil
    })
    if err == nil && token.Valid {
        fmt.Println("valid token")
        return true
    } else {
        fmt.Println("invalid token")
        return false
    }

}
```

Am getting **nil** token as a return, my guess is I have sent bearer and I think it might need parsing if so how?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The server requires a token string without added strings in my case I have added Bearer string to the token string in the header when sending request to the web server i.e.

```
'Authorization':'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token')
```

At the web server we need to split only the valid token without the Bearer string

```
reqToken := r.Header.Get("Authorization")
splitToken := strings.Split(reqToken, "Bearer ")
reqToken = splitToken[1]
```

As a result it becomes valid token without nil.

Comment: In your example you're carrying a space in front of the token (as a result of the split) which is a bad thing. You should either include the space when splitting the string or trim it later

Comment: Yes, it should be "Bearer " (note the space). Else you will get a "illegal base64 data at input byte 0"

Comment: You may catch panic

Answer (score 22):

The answer above is slightly incorrect because after splitting the `reqToken`, there should only be one value in `splitToken`, which is the token itself.

Assuming that the token is of the following format:

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer <YOUR_TOKEN_HERE>'
```

Which is the standard format - with a space between the string "Bearer" and the actual token itself.

The following code will perform the correct token extraction:

```
reqToken := r.Header.Get("Authorization")
splitToken := strings.Split(reqToken, "Bearer")
if len(splitToken) != 2 {
    // Error: Bearer token not in proper format
}

reqToken = strings.TrimSpace(splitToken[1])

fmt.Println(reqToken) // <YOUR_TOKEN_HERE>
```

Comment: You're gonna need to get the `splitToken` at index 1. And also verify that the `splitToken` has a length of 2

Answer (score 5):

Credit: https://github.com/harlow/authtoken/blob/master/authtoken.go

```
const BEARER_SCHEMA = "Bearer "
authHeader := req.Header.Get("Authorization")
token := authHeader[len(BEARER_SCHEMA):]
```

Comment: this will panic if `Authorization` value is shorter than `"Bearer "` - better to ensure via `strings.HasPrefix()`

Comment: You may catch panic error

Answer (score 2):

To be extra resilient to different casing or whitespace preferences, you can also leverage the `strings.Fields` function from the go std lib. This works well:

```
authHeader := req.Header.Get("Authorization")
authFields := strings.Fields(authHeader)
if len(authFields) != 2 || strings.ToLower(authFields[0]) != "bearer" {
  return errors.New("bad authorization header")
}
token := authFields[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

1)here there is the function profilehandler (author theShivaa);

link1: https://gist.github.com/theShivaa/999cec98fc29d77ea47b2bdaf0a6b4fb

link2: https://medium.com/@theShiva5/creating-simple-login-api-using-go-and-mongodb-9b3c1c775d2f

2)to use/test this function, in the bash shell I run this command.

curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization:eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJmaXJzdG5hbWUiOiJwaXBwbzIiLCJsYXN0bmFtZSI6InBpcHBvMyIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoicGlwcG8xZiJ9.MkcI4JNUgoOeMzJUhDe4dLOsK3zXSAGC9fCV5EqwA98" -X GET http://localhost:8080/profile

Comment: The shiva link is discontinued/broken